# Copy Data From Xml To table in database in sql server avoiding duplications

Tags: c#, xml, sql-server-2008

I'm trying to copy data from XML to my database table but I get one approach as best i.e.:

```
using SqlBulkCopy
```

but I'm not able to achieve my task. I need to copy data from XML to SQL database avoiding duplication's in table. and if same data exists dont copy it , if new insert it and updated then make updations in table.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can define a `DataTable` and set all of your columns as `PrimaryKey` like this:

```
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.AddRange(new DataColumn[]{
                new DataColumn("Column1"),
                new DataColumn("Column2"),
                new DataColumn("Column3")});

            dt.PrimaryKey = new DataColumn[] { dt.Columns[0], dt.Columns[1], dt.Columns[2] };

            // Load your data from XML file.

            try
            {
                //dt.Rows.Add(new DataRow)
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }
// BulkCopy Code here.
```

You must load XML file and prepare it for data table structure and add new row to table. When duplicate row added to table, exception occurred but you should leave it.

Good luck.